# StackOverflowError closing dbhelper of a tab activitity

Tags: android

I have a `TabActivity` and two activities with lists related to same db.

I saw that sub activities' `onDestroy()` methods are called before `TabActivity`'s `onDestroy()`, so my `onDestroy()` sub activity method is:

```
listAdapter.getCursor().close();
dataSource = null;
```

while tabActivity is:

```
DBHelper.getHelper(getApplicationContext()).close();
```

where `DBHelper` is a singleton class extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

`TabActivity`'s `onDestroy()` causes stack overflow error...

Comment: you should post the excption stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault...I called my method close() (so overridding original one) and in method definition I didn't call super.close() (in order to actually close db) but the overridden method, thus causing an endless recursion!